# OSError: The CUDA lib64 path could not be located in /usr/lib64

Tags: python, ubuntu, path, gpu

How can I fix this?

```
(cv) jalal@klein:~/computer_vision/py-faster-rcnn/lib$ make
python setup.py build_ext --inplace
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "setup.py", line 58, in <module>
    CUDA = locate_cuda()
  File "setup.py", line 55, in locate_cuda
    raise EnvironmentError('The CUDA %s path could not be located in %s' % (k, v))
OSError: The CUDA lib64 path could not be located in /usr/lib64
Makefile:2: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

I am using this:
https://github.com/rbgirshick/py-faster-rcnn

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Solved this problem using the following change for those who might end of using this popular software (for Cuda ~5):

in `~/computer_vision/py-faster-rcnn/lib/setup.py`

change:

```
cudaconfig = {'home':home, 'nvcc':nvcc,
              'include': pjoin(home, 'include'),
              'lib64': pjoin(home, 'lib64')}
```

to:

```
cudaconfig = {'home':home, 'nvcc':nvcc,
              'include': pjoin(home, 'include'),
              'lib64': pjoin(home, 'lib')}
```

If you are using Cuda7.5 you might need to leave it as lib64 or you might get an error.

Answer (score 4):

This error may also appear if CUDAHOME is not set. Try:

```
$ export CUDAHOME=/usr/local/cuda-8.0
```

Answer (score 1):

For Ubuntu 17.04

Set CUDAHOME in .bashrc file in /home folder to,

```
export CUDAHOME=/usr/lib/nvidia-cuda-toolkit/
```

Then execute `source ~/.bashrc`

Remember to open a new terminal to be able to use the new environment variable.

Change the setup.py file from

```
cudaconfig = {'home':home, 'nvcc':nvcc,
                  'include': pjoin(home, 'include'),
                  'lib64': pjoin(home, 'lib64')}
```

To

```
cudaconfig = {'home':home, 'nvcc':nvcc,
               'include': '/usr/include',
               'lib64': '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu'}
```

Also needed to install `g++5` because `nvcc` doesn't support `g++6`.

```
sudo apt install g++-5
```